# Azure routing through point-to-site then site-to-site

Tags: vpn, routing, azure, gateway

I did have a good hunt around for a similar post but couldn't find the same scenario.  I am trying to connect to a 3rd party URL from an on-prem machine, through Azure.  So:

on-prem -> (point-to-site) -> Azure VPN Gateway -> (site-to-site) -> 3rd party URL

- Point to site address space: 172.16.0.0/24
- Azure vnet address space: 10.3.0.0/16
- 3rd party address space: 10.100.0.0/16

I have put a VM in the Azure network as a middleman for testing, and I can connect from on-prem to the VM, and from the VM to the 3rd party site, however for some reason I can't get all the way through.  The weirdest part is that the 3rd party IP resolves correctly from the hostname, I just can't connect to the URL (it's HTTPS/443 if that matters).  If I run a tracert from on-prem I can see that 'tracert VM' first hop goes straight to the VPN gateway, however 'tracert 3rdparty' goes to my router->isp->fail, so it seems my routing is messed up somehow.

I would have thought this would be pretty standard routing for the VPN gateway, but hopefully there's a way to make this work as it's vital to the project I'm working on.  I'm happy to try custom routes, or whatever it takes. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the routing is not automatic with the VPN gateways, so you may need to actually build a router in Azure and have that forward the packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.  After playing around a bit and some help from Microsoft support, apparently what I had to do was enable BGP on both gateways (Azure and 3rd party), and add a custom route on my on-prem machine.

To add the custom route, after downloading the VPN client from the Azure portal from the VPN Gateway blade and unzipping and installing, edit the routes.txt file %AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Cm\*yourGuid*\routes.txt. Add a route to the 3rd party network address space (in my case 10.100.0.0/16) that goes through the Azure router (10.3.200.5).

In our case we also wanted Azure web apps to be able to do the same thing through [integrating with the VNet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet), in which case we also had to uncheck the 'IKEv2 VPN' checkbox in the Azure gateway point-to-site blade.

Comment: I would make a comment, but I have not enough reputation yet. Sorry...
I came along a [similar problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/993728/azure-site-to-point-vpn-accessing-ressources-connected-through-site-to-site-vpn). I don't know to which IP adresse I have to route my traffic. So, where can I (or did you) find the address of the azure router?

Comment: [M4SX5](https://serverfault.com/users/436041/m4sx5) It's been a long time since I posted this, and the new gateways are slightly different, but when you create a VPN gateway you assign it to a public IP resource (new or existing).  From memory your routes.txt file would have `route add <address> <mask> <gateway>` so in this case
`route add 10.100.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.3.200.5`

Comment: @Jason do you have the information required for the BGP element of the fix? I have a Draytek router on-premise and can't get from client P2S VPN to the on-premise infrastructure, I can only hit the azure machines.

Comment: Can you ping from the Azure machine to on-prem router or machines? Double check your NSGs to ensure traffic (especially ICMP for testing ping) is allowed.

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, Yes. If I am in Azure, I can ping the on-prem machines, even RDP to them, and from on-prem to Azure. The issue is when the clients connect via VPN to Azure. They can see/ping/rdp Azure, but not on-prem. Annoying!